# Maximum number of steps a Turing machine makes

Tags: turing-machines

Given the Turing machine $M = (  \{q_0, q_1, q_2. q_3,q_4\}, \Sigma= \{a, b, c \}, \Gamma = \{a, b, c, \}, \delta, q_0, , \{q_4\} )$ 
where $q_0$ is the start state, $q_4$ the end state and  the blank symbol. $\delta$ is defined as:

[image]

Let $w$ be any word of length $n$ accepted by the Turing machine $M$. Is it always true, that $M$  will reach $q_4$ in maximum of $1.5 \cdot
 (n+5)$ steps?

Is there a general strategy for this or do we just try different inputs until we find a contradiction? If none is found, how do we go about *proving* such a statement?

Comment: Out of curiosity: is $\delta(q_{3},a)$ really $(q_{3},b,L)$?

Comment: Yes, I took this question from an old exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is impossible to even determine if it will ever halt. And if it halts, determining the number of steps is also impossible. Check out [the busy beaver game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver) for details.

There are general techniques that work in a large proportion of cases of practical interest, for a start check out [the reference question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) here. But there have been complete libraries written on the intricacies of the matter...